# correct Awk expression to parse xml to csv

Tags: xml, csv, awk

i wrote a expression to parse my xml into CSV but it doesn't work, could do help me on it please. I do it this way because i can't use a parser like xmlstarlet on the server.

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <record>
   <country>US</country>  
  <data>
            <id_client>50C</id_client>  
            <mail>1@mail.com</mail>
            <adress>10  </adress>
            <num_tel>001</num_tel>
            <name>toto</name>
            <birth>01/30/008</birth>        
  </data> 
  <data>
            <id_client>100K</id_client>  
            <mail>2@mail.com</mail>
            <adress>10  </adress>
            <num_tel>002</num_tel>
            <name>toto2</name>
            <birth>01/30/011</birth>                    
  </data> 
 </ record>
 <record>
   <country>China</country>  
  <data>
            <id_client>99E</id_client>  
            <mail>3@mail.com</mail>
            <adress>10  </adress>
            <num_tel>003</num_tel>
            <name>toto3</name>
            <birth>01/30/0008</birth>       
  </data> 
  <data>
            <id_client>77B</id_client>  
            <mail>4@mail.com</mail>
            <adress>10  </adress>
            <num_tel>004</num_tel>
            <name>toto4</name>
            <birth>2001/05/01</birth>                   
  </data> 
  </record
  </root>
```

the output i need:

```
 country;id_client;name
 US;50C;toto1
 US;100K;toto2
 China;99E;toto3
 China77B;toto4
```

And finaly my syntax i'am trying to update:

```
/<country>/{sub(".*<country[^>]+><[^>]+>","",$0);sub("<.*","",$0);s=s";"$0}/<\/country>/{sub("^;","",s);print s;s=""}
```

Comment: Do you have perl available on the server? Or python? Or ruby? *Any* of those is better suited to this task (with their support for *actual* xml) then awk is.

Comment: @EtanReisner there is an XML library for gawk too. See http://awk.info/?Xgawk and http://sourceforge.net/projects/gawkextlib/files/xgawk/. Caveat: I've never used it so that's about all I know about it.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the link. I knew I'd seen it before but continuously failed to find it again when I wanted to reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're data's always laid out one entry per line like you show with no wacky white space intervening:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[><]"; OFS=";"
    n = split("country id_client name",tags,/ /)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", tags[i], (i<n?OFS:ORS)
    }
 }
{ tag2val[$2] = $3 }
/<\/data>/ {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", tag2val[tags[i]], (i<n?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
country;id_client;name
US;50C;toto
US;100K;toto2
China;99E;toto3
China;77B;toto4
```

If you care about different or additional tags in future, just add them to the list in the `split()` command.

Comment: great it works great !thank you. I understand more and more how the split is essential in awk